# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A35' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

This is my stored procedure that I am trying to execute:

```
Create Procedure CAMP_UpdateCaseProfileID
as

update crcase 

set crcase.UsrProfileNumber = CAMPProfileNumber.ProfileNumberCD 
    ,crcase.UsrManufacturerID = CAMPProfileNumber.ManufacturerID
    ,crcase.UsrTapeModelID = CAMPProfileNumber.TapeModelID
    ,crcase.UsrSerialNbr = CAMPProfileNumber.SerialNbr
    ,crcase.UsrPRegNbr = CAMPProfileNumber.RegistrationNbr
    ,crcase.UsrCAMPLastActuals = current_timestamp

from CAMPProfileNumber 

where crcase.UsrProfileNumber is not null 
        and crcase.CompanyID = 2

GO
```

After creating the procedure the error I am receiving is:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CAMP_UpdateCaseProfileID, Line
>   4 [Batch Start Line 2] Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar
>   value 'A35' to data type int.

Please Help!

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Whatever column contains `A35` isn't an `INT` so you can't update a column which only accepts numbers to that value. Look over your table definitions to narrow down which column is the problem.

Comment: Ok then instead of doing it the way im doing, in which im trying to update a profile ID and its related fields if there is a change to it in a case. 

Do you know of a way to just refresh those fields in SQL?

Comment: This `crcase.UsrProfileNumber = CAMPProfileNumber.ProfileNumberCD` looks highly suspicious. One column name implies number, the other implies string.

Comment: Im learning a lot of SQL as we go and how does one convert a string to a int. Im trying the cast or convert function but not working properly. COuld be missing something

Comment: You can't do what you want if my guess is correct. ProfileNumberCD is a string and it contains values that cannot be converted to an integer(?) to be stored in UsrProfileNumber. There might be workarounds, but those are risky to offer without knowing your schema, your goal, and the decisions you made that lead to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

We could use more information about the relationship between these tables. It sounds like you want to update the records in one table, when there is a change to related records in another table. Depending on the relationship, a foreign key constraint may accomplish what you need.

This is Microsoft's documentation on creating a foreign key:[Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)
Here is information on the options you have when creating the foreign keys:[ALTER TABLE table_constraint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I think the most applicable for this situation being `ON UPDATE CASCADE` but depending on your data retention needs, you may want to look into deletes as well.

The basic principle here is, relate two tables together and "Corresponding rows are updated in the referencing table when that row is updated in the parent table."

Another similar option would be to use [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which is "a special type of stored procedure that automatically runs when an event occurs in the database server." You'll have to be careful with this as you can easily cause dramatic performance issues if you implement it incorrectly.

As LowlyDBA mentioned, the error seems to imply that there is a data type mismatch between at least one column in these tables. This discrepancy would have to be resolved before you use either of these solutions. Depending on what control you have over the tables, if they are supposed to share related data, you may just have to change the columns data type in one table to match the other.